# nginx best practices for reloading servers

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx config which has:

```
events {
   worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
upstream myservers {
   server server1.com:9000;
   server server2.com:9000;
   server server3.com:9000;
}

server {
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined;

  listen 9080;
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://myservers;
  }
 }
}
```

I need to reload the servers and the method I am using is to bring up the new servers on port 9001 and then do `nginx -s reload` with the following modification to the config:

```
upstream myservers {
   server server1.com:9000 down;
   server server2.com:9000 down;
   server server3.com:9000 down;
   server server1.com:9001;
   server server2.com:9001;
   server server3.com:9001;
}
```

Then I bring down the old servers. However, before I bring down the old servers, I need to make sure all workers that were handling requests to these old servers are done. How do I check this? Also, is this the best way to reload backend servers with the free version of nginx?

Comment: what's the difference between the servers on 9000 and 9001 ? the deployed app version ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady yes, its the app version. I am trying to roll out a new version of my app without any downtime.